# How to deploy sass project into Netlify or Heroku?

Tags: css, heroku, sass

I have created a sass project but I don't know how to deploy it before I deploy some other project into Heroku but in cases of sass I am so confused how to deploy it on  production?

sass compiled at the end into CSS so could deploy directly HTML ,CSS and JavaScript part???

If we deploy sass into production so what will the build pack for sass?

I have no idea about it please help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

The Sass file has to be compiled into a CSS file because browsers only recognize CSS for styling. If you're using VSCode, simply install the Sass compiler extension, click 'Watch Sass' and it will compile your Sass file into CSS every time there is a change made. Make sure to link the CSS file to the HTML file.